# How to write $y'''+4y''+3y'+8cos(t)=0$ in the form $x'=Ax+b$ where A is a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

If $x=(y, y', y'')$ and $x'=(y', y'', y''')$, how do I write it in the form above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_1 = y$, then

$x_1' = y' = x_2 \\ x_2' = y'' = x_3 \\x_3' = y''' = -4 y'' - 3 y' - 8 \cos t = -4 x_3 - 3 x_2 - 8 \cos t$

Can you proceed?

**Update** The system can be written as:

$$X' = \begin{bmatrix}x_1'\\x_2'\\x_3'\end{bmatrix}  = Ax + b  = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&-3&-4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\- 8 \cos t\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: A = [0 1 0], [0 0 1], [0 -3 -4] and b = [0 0 -8cos(t)]? (Sorry, not sure how to use mathjax for a matrix...)

Comment: Correct, please see update.